# SSRS Report do not show Subscription option to some end users

Tags: reporting-services, report, subscription

We recently upgraded to Sharepoint 2010 from 2007 and some of SSRS reports are not showing Subscribe option under 'Actions' tab for some of the users.

Please advise what could be the possible issue?

Thanks,
Noman

Answer (score 0):

It could be a permissions issue. The users (or the group they're in) need to have the Create Alerts permission. Is it possible that changes to groups were made when you did the upgrade?

Comment: This is what I guessed, but all users had contribute level access in 2007 which is the same in 2010. Now in Sharepoint 2010 only users with Full Control can see subscribe option but users with Contribute level access don't see that option. I can't allow end users to have full control.

Comment: Can you confirm that the Contribute group has the Create Alert permission level?

Answer (score 0):

Users need "contribute" rights, see this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2012/08/16/sharepoint-adventures-accessdeniedexception-when-a-user-tries-to-add-subscription.aspx